# Displaying an svg file with gradient

Tags: android, xml, svg

I'm building a app for android and my designers using gradient on icons and backgrounds, I can import the icons as png files but i would rather do it with svg file is it possible to do it.

Comment: If it is a pure gradient, you can just even code it without adding any png's.

Answer (score 1):

If, by "SVG", you mean actual SVG files, then the answer is yes. If you really mean VectorDrawable files, then the answer is no.

Comment: `then the answer is yes`,,, if you use a library to read SVG files. Like AndroidSVG.

Comment: The reason I gave both answers is because a lot of people on SO have been using the term "SVG", when they were actually talking about VectorDrawable files.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Yes, of course. *People tend to equate `SVG = VectorDrawable`*. Not knowing that the latter is only a **limited subset** of the former.

Comment: @Amit They are different file formats. When you import an SVG file into Android Studios "Vector Asset tool. it gets converted to a VectorDrawable. The way you tell the difference is SVG files start with `<svg>`, VectorDrawables start with `<vector>`. VectorDrawables can be used directly in an ImageView, SVG files cannot. If you want to use SVG files, you need to use an external library to load and convert them at runtime.

Comment: So if I want to fit it to several screens the only option I have is to make different resolution images

Comment: Fit it? What do you mean? Are you asking a different question now?  If so, start a new question on S.O.  If you instead mean that you want to use gradients, but don't want to use SVGs, then you may need to resort to using PNG files. If you do that, then yes you will probably need to create multiple PNG files for each resolution.

Comment: Another solution would be to draw your path by using the drawing functions and fill it with a gradient.

Comment: Does psd file can be transfer to vectorDrawable?

Comment: PSD (Photoshop) files are bitmaps. VectorDrawables are vector files. So the answer is no.

Comment: Possibly, the **.ai** file format (which is vectorial) is translatable.